# Expression to have equal between range values

Tags: apache-nifi

There is `equals(value)` method in nifi expression language where we can give single value. Let's assume: `equals(1)`. My question is there a possibility to give range of values? Something like: `equals(1-40)`

Answer (score 1):

You rather can use [**le**(*less than or equal to*)](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#lt) **and** [**ge**(*greater than or equal to*)](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#ge) together such as

```
${ value:le(40):and ( ${value:ge(1)} ) }
```

Comment: I even didn't know that expression can be concatinated together... Can i even concat  more expressions together in same line?

Comment: can u answer last question?